# Code blocks in Jinja templates in salt

Tags: python, jinja2, salt-stack

I have a block that looks like this:

```
{% if grains['function'] == 'production' %}
{% set conf_src = "prod.yml.ninja" %}
{% elif grains['function'] == 'staging'] %}
{% set conf_src = "staging.yml.ninja" %}
{% elif grains['function'] == 'dev'] %}
{% set conf_src = "dev.yml.ninja" %}
{% endif %}
```

Is there any way to do something like

```
{% 
    if grains['function'] == 'production'
        set conf_src = "prod.yml.ninja"
    elif grains['function'] == 'staging'
        set conf_src = "staging.yml.ninja"
    elif grains['function'] == 'dev'
        set conf_src = "dev.yml.ninja"
    endif
%}
```

So I can just open the block once?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a look-up dictionary, and only include non-trivial cases:

```
html = '''
{% set lookup = dict(production='prod') %}
{% set conf_src = lookup.get(grains['function'], grains['function']) 
                + '.yml.ninja' %}
'''
```

Here, since `dev` and `staging` are not modified, you may use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) fall-back argument.

Comment: great example of using dict() inside a jinja2 variable set declaration invents_gusts_grain